# Logging with objects using Logback with SocketAppender

Tags: java, logback

I'm trying to use [SocketAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) to log events to a socket server.

The thing I need to send is a custom log object. However it seems as if all the objects are sent as Strings using toString.

Read about it here:

- http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-631
- http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/LoggingEventVO.html (writeObject)

Anyone know how to deal with this? Any suggestions?

Do I have to parse the String and build the object on the server? I am using Logback so that I can add other appenders than the SocketAppender.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

- translate your object into json string using [fastjson](http://code.alibabatech.com/wiki/display/FastJSON/Home);
- pass the json string to the logback function call;
- parse the string and rebuild the object on the server;